# how to perform ligand and DNA alignment in pymol

Tags: dna, pharmacology

I need help in inserting ligand to specific base pair in DNA. I have a drug molecule and want to insert in between the base pairs I am interested in (it is dsDNA). Please note that it is a customed sequence dsDNA so it does not have any intercalation site for the ligand to bind itself. I tried to follow the tutorials but cannot find something where I can insert ligand into the custom DNA sequence I have generated.

I will appreciate if you can please help me or guide me where I can study and understand how to do it.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Is there some reason you are asking this here rather than in [Bioinformatics.SE]? If you agree that site seems more appropriate please either delete from this site and repost there or request migration. Please do not [crosspost](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/) as that is considered to be impolite.

Comment: Could you clarify? Am I right in thinking that you are trying to answer the hypothetical question: “If ligand L were to insert itself between two specific base pairs in my custom dsDNA structure, what molecular interactions would it make?” If so, have you any reason to  think an application to display molecular structures can do this? I would except to have to use some high-powered energy minimizing program to compute possible structures first. Are you sure Pymol has such a facility?